# Как заменить текст по нажатию кнопки?

Tags: jquery, javascript, html

На сайте есть такая строка:

> ХХХ-ХХХ-ХХХ-ХХ Показать телефон

Как сделать, чтоб при клике на показать телефон, появлялся телефон вместо X?

Comment: @websterjoy, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы хотите прятать номер от парсеров то его надо отдавать картинкой, тк любой сотовый куда его не пряч -- отпарсится регуляркой. Если же декоративно, можно так: http://jsfiddle.net/Lbett/1/

```
<a href="#" class="btn__callback" data-phone="+7 (906) 140 2452">Показать телефон</a>

<script>
$('.btn__callback').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var $t = $(this);
    $t.toggleClass('show');

    ($t.is('.show'))?$t.text($t.data('phone')):$t.text('Показать телефон')
});
</script>
```

Comment: А картинку уже и нейросетями можно :)

Answer (score 0):

Ну например [так](http://jsfiddle.net/FlamesoFF/w2PdB/) :)

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('input').val('123-456-789-01');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="ХХХ-ХХХ-ХХХ-ХХ" />
<button>show phone</button>
```